# Как отправить id в name?

Tags: javascript, html, input

У меня есть скрипт который делает автоподгрузку к `<input class="typeahead"/>`

из этого инпата получаем имя **Facebook**

А из `<input id="typeahead"/>` получаем данные в виде **fb**

но мне нужно отправлять данные в `name="search[city]"`
именно из `id="typeahead"`
но отображать для пользователя  `<input id="typeahead" name="search[city]">` не нужно 
можно ли как то передать данные в `name="search[city]` по другому?

```
    <form method="post">
<input class="typeahead"/>
    !--->  <input id="typeahead" name="search[city]"> <---! не нужно 
    </form>
```

Как сам скрипт работает

```js
var stocksData = [
        {
            "company_name": "Facebook",
            "code": "fb",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Google",
            "code": "goog",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Yahoo",
            "code": "yhoo",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Apple",
            "code": "aapl",
        },
        {
            "company_name": "Royal Mail",
            "code": "rmg.l",
        },
     ];
    
    var stocks = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('company_name'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            local: stocksData
        });

        stocks.initialize();

        $('.typeahead').typeahead(
            null, {
            name: 'stocks',
            displayKey: 'company_name',
            source: stocks.ttAdapter()
        }).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, data){            
            $('#typeahead').val(data.code);        
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>

<input class="typeahead" >
<input id="typeahead"/>
```

Comment: а как данные из name начинают отображаться? он же не отвечает за отображение

Comment: @Horchynskyi не из name. ответ ниже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" id="typeahead" name="search[city]">
```

```js
var stocksData = [{
    "company_name": "Facebook",
    "code": "fb",
  },{
    "company_name": "Google",
    "code": "goog",
  },{
    "company_name": "Yahoo",
    "code": "yhoo",
  },{
    "company_name": "Apple",
    "code": "aapl",
  },{
    "company_name": "Royal Mail",
    "code": "rmg.l",
  },
];

var stocks = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('company_name'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: stocksData
});

stocks.initialize();

$('.typeahead').typeahead(
  null, {
    name: 'stocks',
    displayKey: 'company_name',
    source: stocks.ttAdapter()
  }
).on('typeahead:selected', function(event, data) {
  $('#typeahead').val(data.code);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>

<input class="typeahead">
<input type="hidden" id="typeahead" name="search[city]">
```

Comment: Все что нужно только, все равно нужно ставить два инпата только один скрывать вашим методом. Спасибо. Пригодилась html разметка, а я про нее забыл.))